# How can I provide multiple Swagger examples inside a DTO with NestJS?

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

I have a DTO that has several properties, including `creditCard<CreditCardDto>`, `creditCardToken<CreditCardTokenDto>`, `googlePay<GooglePayDto>`, `applePay<ApplePayDto>`. Only one of these properties can exist at a time, so I would like to provide four Swagger examples [like this](https://www.viralpatel.net/openapi-multiple-examples/) for each scenario.

Right now this is what my DTO looks like, with some commented out lines showing what I've tried. It seems like this should be possible, but I must be missing something. Any ideas?

```js
// [...]

  // @ApiExtraModels(CreditCardDto, CreditCardTokenDto, ApplePayDto, GooglePayDto)
  @ApiPropertyOptional({
    examples: {
      CreditCardDto: { value: CreditCardDto },
      CreditCardTokenDto: { value: CreditCardTokenDto },
      ApplePayDto: { value: ApplePayDto },
      GooglePayDto: { value: GooglePayDto },
    },
    // example: ['foo', 'CreditCardTokenDto'],
    description: 'Contains information about credit card.',
  })
  @IncompatibleWith(['creditCardToken', 'applePay', 'googlePay'])
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CreditCardDto)
  @IsOptional()
  creditCard?: CreditCardDto;

  @ApiPropertyOptional({
    examples: {
      CreditCardDto: { value: CreditCardDto },
      CreditCardTokenDto: { value: CreditCardTokenDto },
      ApplePayDto: { value: ApplePayDto },
      GooglePayDto: { value: GooglePayDto },
    },
    // example: CreditCardTokenDto,
    description: 'Contains information about credit card token.',
  })
  @IncompatibleWith(['creditCard', 'applePay', 'googlePay'])
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CreditCardTokenDto)
  @IsOptional()
  creditCardToken?: CreditCardTokenDto;

  @ApiPropertyOptional({
    examples: {
      CreditCardDto: { value: CreditCardDto },
      CreditCardTokenDto: { value: CreditCardTokenDto },
      ApplePayDto: { value: ApplePayDto },
      GooglePayDto: { value: GooglePayDto },
    },
    // example: ApplePayDto,
    description: 'Contains information about Apple Pay.',
  })
  @IncompatibleWith(['creditCard', 'creditCardToken', 'googlePay'])
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => ApplePayDto)
  @IsOptional()
  applePay?: ApplePayDto;

  @ApiPropertyOptional({
    examples: {
      CreditCardDto: { value: CreditCardDto },
      CreditCardTokenDto: { value: CreditCardTokenDto },
      ApplePayDto: { value: ApplePayDto },
      GooglePayDto: { value: GooglePayDto },
    },
    // example: GooglePayDto,
    description: 'Contains information about Apple Pay.',
  })
  @IncompatibleWith(['creditCard', 'creditCardToken', 'applePay'])
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => GooglePayDto)
  @IsOptional()
  googlePay?: GooglePayDto;
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for too.

Comment: Yes, I am also looking for a solution for this.